# Vernam cipher code

Tags: c++

I am trying to write code to implement the vernam cipher in C++, but my code does not run. I don't know what the problem is. The code will get message in zero, one, and key also, and then implement XOR of them to create the cipher text and the same of decrypt method, when I run it it's get me a warnning and stop the run .

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void encrypt(string msg, string key)
{
    while (msg.length() > key.length())
    {
        key += key;
    }
    string encrypt_Text = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= msg.length(); i++)
    {

        encrypt_Text += msg[i] ^ key[i];
    }
    cout << "the cipher text is:" << encrypt_Text << endl;

}

void decrypt(string cipher, string key)
{
    while (cipher.length() > key.length())
    {
        key += key;
    }
    string decrypt_Text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= cipher.length(); i++)
    {

        decrypt_Text += cipher[i] ^ key[i];
    }
    cout << "the messege is:" << decrypt_Text << endl;
}

void main()
{
    string msg, key;
    cout << "enter your messege in boolean : " << endl;
    cin >> msg;
    cout << "enter your key in boolean : " << endl;
    cin >> key;
    encrypt(msg, key);
}
```

Comment: I'm have a tough time understanding what your question is. Can you [edit] your question with the exact text of an error message, or an example input and output demonstrating the problem?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: it's warnning error and not run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `encrypt()` function, try this:

```
encrypt_Text+=((msg[i]-'0')^(key[i]-'0')+'0');
```

Otherwise you're using the ASCII codes of the characters. Also, modify the loop so that it uses `<`, not `<=`.

```
for(size_t i=0; i<msg.length(); i++)
//               ^ smaller, not smaller or equal
```

And modify the return type of `main()` to `int`, this is C++.

Comment: but please , what the msg[i]-'0' mean ??

Comment: `msg[i]` is a `char`, so e.g. `A` is represented as `65`, i.e. its [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/). Now the numbers start at ASCII code `48` for `'0'`, up to `57` for `'9'`, contiguously. So when you write e.g. `'1' - '0'` you get the *number* `1`, which is what you want, and not the ASCII code of `'1'`, which is `49`. Note that the C++ standard does not mandate the use of ASCII, in which the trick mentioned works since the codes are contiguous. If you want to be super super safe can use `atoi` instead.

Comment: so ,my code is perfect to use in implement of "vernam  cipher " ??